# VPython time measurment. Counting passed seconds

Tags: python, time, measurement, vpython

How should I measure number of seconds passed in a infinite loop? I'm using  Vpython, and in my loop i change a position of some elements etc.
The thing is that i have to change color of lights(sphere) every X seconds and it all happens in infinite loop.

```
while True:
    #some stuff
    'here i have to count those seconds'
    #some other stuff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could determine the elapsed time by calling [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time), and taking the difference.

> i have to change color of lights(sphere) every X seconds

Say you last changed the colour at time `T`. Keep calling `time.time()` inside the loop, and change the colour again when `time.time() - T` exceeds `X`.

Comment: Ok, but with what function i should initiate the first time?

Comment: It works now, I'll try though mgilson way as well and see which one is better.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [`timeit.default_timer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer) to figure out what time it is and compute the difference.

e.g.:

```
from timeit import default_timer
clock_start = default_timer()
#... do something here
clock_end = default_timer()
print "This took %s seconds" %( clock_end - clock_start )
```